# MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'match (aanbieder_id, vrager_id) VALUES ((' 64 ','6'))' at line 1

Tags: php, sql

My code:

```
<?php 

session_start(); 

include('connection.php');

$vrager_id = $_SESSION['vrager_id'];
$aanbieder_id = $_GET['aanbieder_id'];
echo $vrager_id. '<br>';
echo $aanbieder_id.'<br>';

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO match
        (aanbieder_id, vrager_id) VALUES ('$aanbieder_id', '$vrager_id' ) ") 
        or die(mysql_error()); 
        
        mysql_close($mysql);
        
?>
```

My output:

> 6
>
> 64
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'match (aanbieder_id, vrager_id) VALUES ((' 64 ','6'))' at line 1

I also included a picture of my database if that somewhat helps:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

`match` is a [reserved keyword within MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html). If you want to use it as an identifier, enclose it in backticks (as you should always do with identifiers):

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `match`
        (aanbieder_id, vrager_id) VALUES ('$aanbieder_id', '$vrager_id' ) ")
```

<sup>`mysql_` functions are deprecated. See [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) or [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) for replacements!</sup>

Comment: Well thank you very much good sir! (punches himself in the face)

Answer (score 1):

`MATCH` is a [MySQL reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html).

You can use reserved words for table names only if you delimit them:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `match`
    (aanbieder_id, vrager_id) VALUES ('$aanbieder_id', '$vrager_id' ) ")
```

PS: You have a grievous SQL injection vulnerability. Never take values from $_GET and copy them directly into your queries. See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)